# Magento2 set maintenance mode

Tags: magento2, maintenance

I am enabling maintenance mode by adding a file `var/.maintenance.flag`, but i am getting the error:

```
Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 
#0 /backup/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->assertMaintenance()
#1 /backup/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#2 {main}
```

I even tried enabling it using the command:

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Also, enabled the production mode, cleared caches still I am not getting 503 page. Please help!

Answer (score 16):

Maintenance mode means that the website is offline.
So it works as expected.
If you want to remove the maintenance mode run `bin/magento maintenance:disable`

Comment: Shouldn't it be showing: "The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later." i.e. 503.phtml?

Comment: You are probably right. But not sure

Comment: This does not answer the question of the exception.

Answer (score 16):

My `MAGE_MODE` was set to developer and I had deployed in production using:

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

assuming that it is a dynamic way of changing the developer mode to production.

I had to change the `MAGE_MODE` to `production` or `default` to get the 503 page.

I would love to know the difference between `MAGE_MODE` and deploy mode.

Comment: I think the values you set on the server config (like MAGE_MODE) override the values from `config.php` and `env.php`. That's why your developer mode was on even if you set it differently via cli.

Comment: You are right!!..I din't find anything in `config.php` but in `env.php` it does changes the `MAGE_MODE` value based on the cli command. Thanks :)

Comment: Where to change it?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in Magento `developer mode` -> then activate `maintenance mode` -> you will get the error message you have described

When you are in any other mode -> then activate `maintenance mode`-> you will get the 503 page

Comment: Seem, it doesn't matter which mode you use, it shows an exception always.

Answer (score 1):

> You can try this.
> Run the following command.(As I have not tested this, Please create a backup of your Magento)

1. `/bin/magento maintenance:disable`

If Not resolved using the first command and you see an error like "**The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later**".In that case, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315115/how-can-i-disable-magento-2-maintenance-mode-without-using-ssh/36331974#36331974).

2. Now run the command: `/bin/magento maintenance:status`
3. `/bin/magento maintenance:enable`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design your maintenance page you need to edit file pub/errors/default/503.phtml and for css pub/errors/default/css/styles.css design accordingly.

And in .htaccess page need to comment ##  SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer or production for execute this maintenance page.

and if you are in production mode then this page will excute other then below code error will show.

```
Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 
#0 /backup/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->assertMaintenance()
#1 /backup/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#2 {main}
```

if you want to come back in your website you need to delete var/.maintenance file or run below command in terminal

```
//For run your website back online.
php bin/magento maintenance:disable  
//For on maintenance mode.
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Also set in .htaccess

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Open **pub/.htaccess** (or **.htaccess** if you configured your webserver the wrong way) and add this:

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE production
```

Afterwards remove it again.